# JIRA: Export list of issues with link hierarchy

Tags: tools

I'm trying to find a way to export the list of JIRAS from a project, but respsecting the link hierarchy (issue is key, belongs, etc). The major restriction is that the JIRA setup does not have GreenHopper installed and I'm not able to access the admin to install external plugin.

Does anyone know any way to extract this type of report from the webclient, the desktop client or any external reporting tool.

For example:

```
Key      | Summary                               | Attributes ...
JIRA-1   | Main issue (is key issue)             | Atr  N ...
  JIRA-2 | Child issue (has JIRA-1 as key issue) |
```

Answer (score 3):

If it helps, you can configure JIRA to show a column with the linked issues. You can then export this to Excel, and use the table formatting features in Excel to get the view you want.

To do this:

1. Perform a search in JIRA
2. [Configure the issue navigator](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Customising+your+Issue+Navigator) to show the 'Linked Issues' column
3. Export this to Excel by selecting 'Views' -> 'Excel (Current fields)'
4. In Excel, you have a column named 'Key', and another column called 'Linked Issues'. Format this as required.

If I have misunderstood the output you need, I would suggest reposting your question over at https://answers.atlassian.com where  somebody with more JIRA expertise is likely to see it.

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: In a round of enhancements on a recent project, we saved 80 hours of development by saying "Can we just add an export to Excel function?" rather than baking the functionality into the app. At first I was like "That's kind of lame" but when you look at it from the reinventing-the-wheel department, sometimes it's just a lot easier to dump the data to CSV and load it up in Excel!

Answer (score 0):

**[Better Excel Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.betterexcel) provides an enhanced Excel export feature** for JIRA:

- It has strong data types (the built-in feature produces all text output)
- It supports formulas, functions, pivot tables and all the bells and whistles in Excel
- It can be automated and scripted
- It is compatible with Open Office and Numbers

See the [full comparison and documentation](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-better-excel-plugin/#comparison).

Comment: It sure looks better, from what I remember of JIRA back in the day. That said... does that plugin support the issue hierarchy? I reviewed the link and couldn't find something that conclusively said it did.

Comment: In JIRA, there are only two levels in hierarchy: issues and their children called sub-tasks. If you meant this, then yes, the Better Excel Plugin fully supports both.

Answer (score 0):

[Kualitee](http://www.kualitee.com) a test management tool has an exclusive integration with JIRA. It also features link hierarchy in it's interface and allows you to export those files under different formats. Its also free up to 20 users.